# Android - java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android

I'm facing a recurrent problem that I don't know why it is happening. It happens all of a sudden. I didn't do anything different from what I was doing before.

I'm using these tabs: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

When I open one of the three tabs (Class name = Tab1), this problem comes out. Before, this error came out after clicking all of the tabs (????).
A part of the stack trace:

---

Could not find class 'org.android.catsMobile.packageName.Tab1$OrderAdapter', refereced from method org.android.catsMobile.packageName.Tab1.onCreate
[...]

threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
java.lang.VerifyError: org.android.catsMobile.packageName.Tab1

---

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by reducing the number of times when I use this method:

```
SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("CATS", 0);
String sid = preferencias.getString("sid", null);
```

I used a static field in one of the classes and it's working just fine.